# Effective way to perform many http requests per second in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, web-crawler

I am working on webcrawler. It is possible to perform many requests (say, 500-1000 per second) without creation thread per each request(I don't mean thread pools, reusing and so on)?

Comment: You don't want thread pools and thread reuse, but you don't want to create threads, but yet what you're asking for pretty much requires high parallelization. I don't understand what you expect as an answer.

Comment: Out of curiosity, are you aware of [Nutch](http://nutch.apache.org/) or any of the [other Java web crawlers](http://java-source.net/open-source/crawlers)? Why do you want to write your own?

Comment: 1.I just that I want 500~1000 simultaneously connections to different servers. My tests show that is hard to have 500-1000 threads run simultaneously. So I am looking for cheaper way to create connections.
2. I was working with Nutch. First of all, it's hard to get access to raw files. Also,it slows down after 5-6 hours of work. It's possible to increase performance by means of cluster, but anyway I don't know why it works so slow by default. I checked Heririx also and faced similar issues - performance degradation, lack of documentation, terrible spring config in H3.

Comment: you can extend a `ThreadPoolExecutor` and limit the thread pool size in the constructor.

Comment: It sounds like you want java.util.concurrent.Executors.newFixedThreadPool(nThreads) to gain some parallelism without having "500-1000 threads run simultaneously".

Comment: If you've tried `Nutch`, `Heritrix`, and possibly other solutions and they didn't work for you, you should edit that info back into your question.  Potential Answerers like to know what you've already tried and aren't always motivated to read all the comments.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want here is that a single thread can handle n number of requests simultaneously.

Now that would mean interleaving the steps for handling 2 threads. That would make sense only if there was some "blocking" operation.

Now, one might say, yes we do block. So what I want is

1. Request 1 is made and I am waiting for the response
2. Initiate request 2 while waiting for request 1s response is to come  response.
3. Get request 1's response and process it
4. Get request 2's response and process it.

This would be possible only if HTTP was "asynchronous". Unfortunately it is not.
(An ok read -> http://wiki.answers.com/Q/Why_http_is_asynchronous)
There are some "asynchronous" HTTP clients which do what AJAX in browser does.

It allows the thread initiating the call to continue. The response is provided back in the call back.

Truth is that they have a thread pool which process these calls synchronously. Only it appears asynchronous.

Exampe:

http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-asyncclient-dev/index.html